# Perform operation on part of a table / create a reference

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

There is a function `f` that I would like to operate on a rectangular part of a table `t`. The part is specified by function

```
Part[t, Sequence @@ (Span @@ # & /@ rect)]
```

This would work as I intended

```
Part[t, Sequence @@ (Span @@ # & /@ rect)] = Map[f, Part[t, Sequence @@ (Span @@ # & /@ rect)], {2}] ]
```

But I have to repeat this long, tedious `Part` twice. I tried alternative ways:

```
(*attempt 1*)
With[   {part=Part[t, Sequence @@ (Span @@ # & /@ rect)]},
        part = Map[f,part,{2}]]      ]

(*attempt 2*)
(part = Map[f,part,{2}])/.{part->Part[t, Sequence @@ (Span @@ # & /@ rect)]}
```

But they wouldn't work. How can I make a "reference", or a "pointer" to the part that I want to operate on, without making a copy of it? Thanks!

Comment: Please add minimal example and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're after yet, but if you're looking to Map a function to a submatrix, try [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html)

```
matrix = Array[# &, {3, 3}]
MapAt[E^# &, matrix, {2 ;; 3, 2 ;; 3}] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

You could also use [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)

```
ReplacePart[
  matrix,
  {i_?(MemberQ[{2, 3}, #] &), j_?(MemberQ[{2, 3}, #] &)} -> f@matrix[[i, j]]
  ] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You may consider

```
spec = Sequence @@ (Span @@ # & /@ rect);
Part[t, spec]
```

or

```
t[[spec]]
```

This would lead to:

```
With[{spec = Sequence @@ (Span @@ # & /@ rect)},
 t[[spec]] = Map[f, t[[spec]], {2}]]
```